# Visual Studio 2013RC Out of Memory

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 RC is throwing out of memory error after I exit the program. This happens nearly every single time.

I am looking for the solution, if it exits, to this problem.

Comment: I've been using 2013 since the preview and RC was released and have not had a single problem.  It actually seems faster to me.  You gave very little information, and you have to remember it's not a stable build.  I'm not sure what you want folks here at StackOverflow to say...

Comment: @Adam its not for stack overflow. Its for Microsoft. They read these and hopefully will take notice. In my experience, the installer failed completely to install and now I am getting out of memory every time I close the program and try to re-open. Maybe my luck but never seen any issues with previous Visual Studio versions like this.

Comment: SO isn't a Microsoft bug reporting tool

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/

Comment: @Adam Well, at any rate, it is still a legit question. I'm fairly sure that this will happen to others and maybe someone else figure it out. Hope so.

Comment: I don't think they guarantee that they will look at this. They, as many many sites do, recommend this site for help. You could get on MS's forum and get quicker, and in this case probably better, responses.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio, go to Tools-->Options... . Expand the Test Tools node and select Test Execution. Under Performance, uncheck the "Keep test execution engine running between test runs" checkbox.

This should resolve the problem you are experiencing.

and go for this article very Helpful

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx